# Need Oracle SQL query which will find out consecutive occurrence of vowels for more than 2 times

Tags: sql, oracle

Need to have an Oracle SQL query which will find out the rows where specific field value has consecutive occurrence of vowels for more than 2 times. Moe than 2 consecutive vowels - can be anywhere within the string. E.g.

```
Field
----------  
Asdfaadgr    
Aeirdth    
Whbtreiou    
Oaxxxx    
Yyyyueoattt
```

From above, below will be selected

```
Aeirdth
Whbtreiou
Yyyyueoattt
```

I am using Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: Use `regexp_like` function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use regex for cases like this:

```
Select A,B,C
From Table
Where REGEXP_LIKE(Field, '[aeiou]{3,}', 'i');
```

This returns all the rows where 'Field' has 3 or more consecutive vowels(case-insensitive).

Comment: `regexp_like`, not `regex_like`

Comment: It might be an interesting exercise to enhance this regexp for "globalized" vowels. You know, things like á, ü, ä, ó, ô, ...

Comment: mmm.. interesting the `'i'` parameter